# Python: PyCrypto RSA binascii.Error: Incorrect padding while reading keys from a file

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa, pycrypto

I'm trying to encrypt the data in a file using AES encryption and then encrypt the AES key using RSA. But when i try to read the keys from the file it crops up with the error "RSA binascii.Error: Incorrect padding".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dbane_000/PycharmProjects/RSE/RSA.py", line 33, in <module>
    key=RSA.importKey(f.read())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 660, in importKey
    der = binascii.a2b_base64(b('').join(lines[1:-1]))
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

The error doesn't come always but maybe once for every five times that I run this code. What could be the reason?

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto import Random
import rsa
import base64
import os

BLOCK_SIZE = 32
PADDING = '{'

pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING

EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)

random_generator = Random.new().read
rsakey = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
f=open('key.pem','w')
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(rsakey.publickey())
f.write(rsakey.exportKey("PEM"))
f.write(rsakey.publickey().exportKey("PEM"))
f.close()
f=open('key.pem','r')
key=RSA.importKey(f.read())
pubkey=key.publickey()
f.close()
secret = os.urandom(BLOCK_SIZE)
print secret
crypto =pubkey.encrypt(secret, 32)
secret =key.decrypt(crypto)

print crypto
print secret

cipher = AES.new(secret)


# encode a string
f=open('plaintext.txt','r')
plaintext=f.read()
f.close()
encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, plaintext)
print 'Encrypted string:', encoded
f=open('cipher_data.txt','w')
f.write(encoded)
f.close()

# decode the encoded string
decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encoded)
print 'Decrypted string:', decoded
f=open('plaintext.txt','r')
plaintext=f.read()
f.close()
f=open('decrypted.txt','w')
f.write(decoded)
f.close()
```

Comment: You're not opening your files in binary mode...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes to open files in binary mode this should be the code right ? f=open('key.pem','rb') . I tried it but still no difference.

Comment: Hmmm. Usually the public key part is contained in the private key. Did you try to not export the public key explicitly? For PEM text mode is probably OK, but certainly not for the ciphertext.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to check the contents of the input files from where you are taking key or data to encrypt or decrypt. This type of error would may occur,if the data from f.read() is in a desired format to perform decrypt.. And please try to write those keys or data at begining or desired index and fetch from that index..

```
# please check at this statements
f=open('key.pem','w')
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(rsakey.publickey())
f.write(rsakey.exportKey("PEM"))
f.write(rsakey.publickey().exportKey("PEM"))
f.close()
f=open('key.pem','r')
key=RSA.importKey(f.read())
pubkey=key.publickey()
f.close()

I hope this may help you..
```